# Do SharePoint-hosted apps have a persistent PropertyBag

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-hosted-app

I'm trying to store some user-configurable settings inside a PropertyBag.

The getters and setters seem to work correctly, at least while the app is still open, but when I refresh the app's page it appears that the PropertyBag is empty, and none of the things that I added to it were saved.

Is a SharePoint-hosted app's PropertyBag not a valid place to store properties?

Here's my setter, in case something is flawed with it.

```
//Property Bag Setter           
        function setPropertyBag(item, value) {

            currentContext.load(web);
            var webProperties = web.get_allProperties();
            currentContext.load(webProperties);

            webProperties.set_item(item, value);
            web.update();

            currentContext.executeQueryAsync(setPropertySuccess, setPropertyFail);
        }

        function setPropertySuccess(sender, args) {
            alert("Setting success");
        }

        function setPropertyFail(sender, args) {
            alert("Failed to set property. Here's what we know about the problem: " + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```